# AWS Athena generic internal error when querying a table Glue created because 'columns has 110 elements while columns. Types has 106 elements!'

Tags: aws, csv, rdbms

This error happens to me anytime I try to query the 'airports' table in my database which was created by a glue crawler I created for this purpose along with 3 other datasets. They were all csv files beforehand, and I have performed each and every step of this process already in MySQL Workbench locally before trying it out on the cloud in AWS right now and I never got any errors like this when querying my airports dataset there. All I did was run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM "runway_db_athena"."airports" limit 10;
```

And this is the error message I got back:

> GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: SerDeException thrown initializing deserializer org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe. Cause: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe: columns has 110 elements while columns.types has 106 elements!
> This query ran against the "runway_db_athena" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or contact customer support  with Query Id: 1b71aed6-8e34-4618-9568-930c1b19dd92

Just as a sanity check before posting here after getting feedback on AWS's re:Post forum that this error typically means you have a csv with more fields than the ones identified by the crawler, so, I opened up the file, hit Ctrl+-> and saw that there are 106 columns, then I opened up MySQL Workbench, created a new database, and imported this csv file using its Data Table Import Wizard, then ran a DESC and a SELECT on it and both worked just fine. Plus, Workbench triple confirmed that the 110 was the off number:

```
3   21  04:08:29    desc `airportandrunwaydata`.airports    106 row(s) returned 0.000 sec / 0.000 sec
```

And here is what that description table looks like:
[image]

Comment: @J.D. I knew I should have included a screenshot, I'll be right back with that. The DESC function returns a table with two columns where each row describes each of the columns in the actual database table being described.